# Read yaml file with vue.js from disk (not URL)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, yaml

In Vue.js I would like to read a YAML file from my filesystem (this file is not available online so can not be requested via URL), convert it to JSON and somehow *expose* it in a way that all components can access it. How can I do it?

I should probably use [js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) but I can't find a way for it to work in Vue.js.

Comment: https://npm.taobao.org/package/yamljs

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing the problem, but

```
npm install yaml-js --save
```

then import into component and use

```
<script>
  import { yaml } from 'yaml-js' 
  // or maybe the following, try both
  import yaml from 'yaml-js'
```

Your biggest problem would be the location of the Yaml file to be read in. I'm reading files from the static folder, so if you can locate it there you should be able to read it with

```
return Vue.http.get('Yaml.whatever')
  .then(response => {
    // process response.body
```

In main.js set up the root path (must be within your web site)

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.http.options.root = './static/'
```

Comment: This file is not available via URL (it is not available within web site) .. File is stored in filesystem. I want that yaml file data would seen directly in JS file (precompiled itd).

Comment: Then you'd need to, say, create an [Electron app](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/vue-electron) to bring node fs to the party.